# Pivot table - need to include blank values as null

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I am attempting to use mySQL to change to modify (pivot) a table:

```
WMU     YEAR     CPUE
 a       1987       22
 a       1988       32
 a       1989       2
 a       1990       34   
 b       1988       5
 b       1990       4
```

Needs to be:

```
WMU     CPUE_1987     CPUE_1988    CPUE_1999    CPUE_1990
 a           22           32         2             34
 b           5            null       null           4
```

I have tried using a SELECT and JOIN statement:

```
select t.wmu, 
tb2.CPUE as CPUE_1987, 
tb3.CPUE as CPUE_1988, 
tb4.CPUE as CPUE_1989, 
tb5.CPUE as CPUE_1990,
from muledeerharvest2011 as t 
JOIN muledeerharvest2011 as tb2 
JOIN muledeerharvest2011 as tb3 
JOIN muledeerharvest2011 as tb4 
JOIN muledeerharvest2011 as tb5
WHERE tb2.year = 1987 and t.WMU = tb2.WMU
and tb3.year = 1988 and t.WMU = tb3.WMU
and tb4.year = 1989 and t.WMU = tb4.WMU
and tb5.year = 1990 and t.WMU = tb5.WMU:
```

This only works for "WMU" entries that have all of the "YEAR" values.  Rows such as b in the example will not be selected at all.

Is there any way I can modify this statement so that blank year values appear as null in the output?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got the **Question** right, Then the following Query will get you the Solution.

You are not getting and values because you are **`INNER JOIN (JOIN)`**. **`LEFT JOIN`**  will do the **trcik**

```
select distinct
t.wmu, 
tb2.CPUE as CPUE_1987, 
tb3.CPUE as CPUE_1988, 
tb4.CPUE as CPUE_1989, 
tb5.CPUE as CPUE_1990
from muledeerharvest2011 as t 
LEFT JOIN muledeerharvest2011 tb2 
   on tb2.Year = 1987 and t.WMU = tb2.WMU
LEFT JOIN muledeerharvest2011 tb3 
   on tb3.Year = 1988 and t.WMU = tb3.WMU
LEFT JOIN muledeerharvest2011 tb4 
   on tb4.Year = 1989 and t.WMU = tb4.WMU
LEFT JOIN muledeerharvest2011 tb5 
   on tb5.Year = 1990 and t.WMU = tb5.WMU
```

Here is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f1f3/1)**

Answer (score 0):

This can also be written using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select wmu,
  sum(case when year=1987 then cpue end) CPUE_1987,
  sum(case when year=1988 then cpue end) CPUE_1988,
  sum(case when year=1989 then cpue end) CPUE_1989,
  sum(case when year=1990 then cpue end) CPUE_1990
from muledeerharvest2011 
group by wmu;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5342/2)